# Docker Compose - Wrong hostname during build

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, puppet

`hostname -f` returns blank during build time, but returns the correct hostname after build is complete.

I need `hostname -f` to return the provided hostname, as I'm running Puppet within the container.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you need the hostname for Puppet?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is, that during the building process the container is not running ... so if the container isn't running you can't get a hostname ...

Comment: Makes sense... any chance a hostname can be forced during build time?

Comment: What do you want to do with the hostname? For me a hostname is a relative static thing and not really useful in such environment like docker ...

Comment: The masterless local dev Puppet config relies on the hostname being "dev-admin.local"

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need a separate config for hostnames in docker ... docker is communicating by its service names.

If you use docker-compose and suppose the following config

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
    build: docker/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}:/app:ro"
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - server
  php:
    build: docker/php-fpm
    expose:
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - "${PROJECT_ROOT}:/app"
    networks:
      - server
```

Because the images "nginx" and "php" are in the same network "server" they easily can communicate with each other by calling the name of the service as the host ...
So you can for example connect to the container "nginx" and "ping php" ... you don't have to care about ip's or host names.
So you only have to update your config file where "dev-admin.local" is called and replace it with the desired host.